# What happened to side marker reflectors?

Tags: safety

I was looking at an older car recently and noticed its side reflector was missing.  Then I realized, cars dont have side marker reflectors anymore.  What happened to them?  I assume there was a U.S. law requiring them...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CFR 49 states that a reflective area is required.

Manufacturers have blended the turn signals into dual purpose units that are reflectors as well as signal lamps.  The lenses have reflective properties built into them.  If you shine a light on the side of a vehicle you will see these properties when the car running lights are turned off.

I noticed this myself a few years ago and researched it.  I had noticed the same thing and became curious.  I started with DOT website and wound up in the CFR's.

Here is a [link](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/49/571.108) to CFR 49

CFR = Code of Federal Regulations